# LSTM input layer shape in Keras using functional API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement LSTMs on drug data the shape of the data is given below also the model but it throws an error which is `Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`.
Can please somebody help that what will be the input shapes for the model thanks in advance.

```
############### Shape of Data ############

x_train shape (29790, 1144)

y_train_one_hot shape (29790, 65)

x_test shape (7474, 1144)

y_test_one_hot shape (7474, 65)
```

`############# code for the model ###########`

```
event_num = 65
droprate = 0.3
vector_size = 572

def DNN():
    train_input=Input(shape=(29790,1144),name='Inputlayer')
    train_in=LSTM(512)(train_input)
    # train_in=BatchNormalization()(train_in)
    train_in=Dropout(droprate)(train_in)
    train_in=LSTM(256)(train_in)
    # train_in=BatchNormalization()(train_in)
    train_in=Dropout(droprate)(train_in)
    train_in=Flatten()(train_in)
    train_in=Dense(event_num)(train_in)
    out=Activation('softmax')(train_in)
    model=Model(input=train_input,output=out)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
dnn.fit(x_train, y_train_one_hot, batch_size=128, epochs=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test_one_hot),
                    callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

[image: Code Error Pic]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `Embedding Layer` inbetween `Input` and `LSTM` because the `LSTM` layers requires `3D input`

2nd mistake is the `shape` to the `Input Layer` cannot include `batch_size`

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
train_input=Input(shape=(1144,),name='Inputlayer')
emb_op = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,output_dim=required_embedding_dim) (train_input)
train_in=LSTM(512)(emb_op)
```

3rd mistake is add `(return_sequences = True) for the LSTM` in the `line number 2` of the `DNN function`

4th mistake is the `keyword` for `Model` should be `inputs and outputs` not `input and output`

`model=Model(inputs=train_input,outputs=out)`

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to give return_sequences= True for the LSTM layers. And also you can implement dropout with LSTM layer. No need to keep it as a separate layer
`LSTM(512, return_sequences = True, dropout = droprate)(train_input)`

Comment: I use return_Sequence = True but I got this error ValueError: Error when checking input: expected Inputlayer to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (29790, 1144)